# replace specific line in file text

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string text;
  int line;
  cout << "Text: ";
  cin >> text;
  cout << "Line: ";
  cin >> line;

  fstream file;

  file.open("main.txt", ios::in | ios::out);

  vector<string> lines;
  string index;

  while (getline(file, index))
  {
    lines.push_back(index);
  }

  line--;
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
  {
    if (i != line)
    {
      file << lines[i] << endl;
    } else
    {
      file << text << endl;
    }
  }
  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I want to change specific text in my file text but my code isnt work.
Could someone help me what is the issue in my code.
*Note: I just see vector in C++ in the first time, so my code can be had many problem.

```
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
LINE 4
LINE 5
```

this is my file text (main.txt)

Comment: Open the file for reading only, read into the vector, *close the file*. Modify the vector and its contents as needed (very easy if you have the line-number, as the vector index is the line-number minus one). Then open the file for writing (truncating any existing contents), and write the new contents of the vector.

Comment: We cant read and write in one times ?

Comment: No that really don't work very well.

Comment: Could you help me how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

###### Use separate steps for Read/Update/Write

@Some programmer dude suggests a great approach for solving this problem:

> Open the file for reading only, read into the vector, close the file. Modify the vector and its contents as needed. Then open the file for writing (truncating any existing contents), and write the new contents of the vector.

You want to use this approach, because the length of a line might change during updates.

There are techniques for opening a file for both input and output at the same time, but they don't work if line lengths are changed. If you write a new line 3, for instance, that is shorter than the old line 3, then some of the old line 3 will still remain in the file.

And if the new line 3 is longer than the old one, then you will overwrite part of line 4.

So it is best to stage the operations separately from each other:

1. read
2. update
3. write

###### A pseudo-code solution

Here is some pseudo-code to get you started.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

bool read_file(std::string const& file_name,
    std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
    bool good{ true };
    // Open file for input.
    // Read file, one line at a time.
    // Call push_back to add each line to vector lines.
    // If file open fails, or a read operation fails
    //   for a reason other than eof, set good to false.
    return good;
}
bool update(std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
    bool good{ true };
    // Get text and line number from user.
    // Update vector lines.
    // If the user cancels the update, set good to false.
    return good;
}
void write_file(std::string const& file_name,
    std::vector<std::string> const& lines)
{
    // Open file for output.
    // Write file.
}
int main()
{
    std::string file_name{ "main.txt" };
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    if (read_file(file_name, lines) && update(lines))
        write_file(file_name, lines);
    return 0;
}
```